# Exjts4: How to set a column in a GridPanel dynamically to hidden

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, gridpanel

in my GridPanel I have different Columns.
Now I want dynamically set a few of them to hidden:true.
I gave the columns ID's but I have no success on it.
For example

```
Ext.getCmp("mainfield").setHidden(true);
```

Doesn't work. Any ides or help? THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grid.columns[columnIndex].hide();
```

or

```
grid.columns[columnIndex].setVisible(false);
```

To find column by id use `down`:

```
grid.down('gridcolumn#mainfield').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is [hide](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-hide):

```
Ext.getCmp("mainfield").hide();
```